# programmatic zoom and pan chartjs with logarithmic scale

Tags: chart.js

In chartjs (v3) I'm programmatically zooming and panning by setting the min and max values for a series.

This works great, except if the series has a logarithmic scale ... this method doesn't seem to work, and has some strange results.

Any ideas on how I can achieve programmatic panning and zoom with logarithmic scales?  Simply adding/subtracting the min/max values doesn't work correctly

EDIT: I see that the zoom plugin API has a zoomScale() function, but setting the min and max has the same effect... should min and max be calculated differently for logarithmic scales?

EDIT2: I'm trying to call the pan() function, which accepts Scale[] as a parameter ... I'm strugging to work out how to pass one of my scales, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For zooming and panning, I'm using Zoom plugin: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom

You can also find a specific sample on log axis: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/samples/wheel/log.html

Comment: Yep I'm using that plugin too for zoom/pan with mouse, but I also have to be able to do it programmatically... is it possible to do that with this plugin?

Comment: Yes, there are APIs to do that: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/blob/5849dda119828e915498ece394e7d142522c6b84/types/index.d.ts#L48-L54

Comment: Have a look to the sample in the doc site: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/latest/samples/api.html

Comment: Thanks, yep I've tried using the chart.zoomScale('y', {min: 0, max: 100}, 'default') method... problem is that with logarithmic scale the min and max values I supply make it go wack

Comment: The calculation of min and max is the same for all scales. I think we need an example of your impl in order to reproduce the issue. The same for panning. Myabe you could raise an issue in github to the project.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar problem, I've got it working ...

I simply need to call the pan function like this:

mychart.pan(10, [mychart.scales['yMyScale']], 'none');